# Running a script at shutdown

Tags: shutdown, scripts

I've read the answers to this and similar questions already, but so far none had worked for me.

On my Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) system, all the files in `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc0.d/` are links.  I put my script (called *shutdown_script*) in the `/etc/init.d/` directory and created two symbolic links to it, one in `/etc/rc0.d/` and the other in `/etc/rc6.d`, both with the name *K99shutdown_script*.  The script is not being run at shutdown, which is what I want.  The script is just to test if I could run a script at shutdown; I supply the code in shutdown_script below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# Tests script to run at shutdown.
# Script creates a fil and writes to it. 
#
# Usage: ./shutdown-script

touch $HOME/shutdown.log
echo "Shutting down at `date` ..." >> $HOME/shutdown.log
```

As you can see, it just adds a file to the home folder showing the current date and time.

Please could you tell me what I may be doing wrong, and more importantly, how to get a script to run at shutdown.

Comment: My Freinds , take care of formats before posting.

Comment: I suppose you mean all the files in /etc/rc0.d/ and /etc/rc6.d/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle what you are doing is correct. My guess is you may be looking in the wrong place for that `shutdown.log` file you are trying to create. Since these scripts will be executed at shutdown by root, the variable `$HOME` will not point to your usual home directory. See if `/root/shutdown.log` has been created, or supply an absolute path in your script without the `$HOME` variable.

Comment: Thank you Malte Skoruppa!  Yes it was the $HOME variable.  I found no  shutdown.log in /root.

Comment: Glad I could help! If it solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted. Happy holidays to you :)