# Ensure that a (potentially long) root script execute to completion before power-down

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, init.d, runlevel

I want to run a simple `rsync`-based bash script as root when a power-down cycle initiates from either:

- a login interactive shell, or
- a gui session, or
- a machine boot state where no login-user has opened a session (e.g. perhaps a headless server ?)

i.e. irrespectively of whether power down is initiated from a console-like session, from a gui-login session or from an internal mechanism (e.g. cron scheduling or ssh instructions passed remotely, ...).

Note that by *power-down* I mean either *shutdown* (rc0) or *reboot* (rc6).

For the use-case *"run script in context of a gui session"*, @Krytarik offers a [solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918649) on UF (see #2 in thread), based on `lightdm`. The solution (repeated elsewhere on AU, viz [[ref2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68407/where-do-i-place-a-logout-script-for-lightdm), [[ref3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102061/root-script-execution-at-non-root-user-login-logout)) only addresses running a script at gui session logout via configuration of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, NOT immediately before *machine power-down* which is what I want...

***EDIT:***
The alternative is a script triggered at certain run-levels, but because in that script `rsync` will deal with up to 2~3 GB of data, the power-down sequence must pause during script execution and automatically resume after completion. I found:

- a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391594/running-a-script-at-shutdown?rq=1) based on placing `K##-scriptname.sh` script directly in `/etc/rcX.d/`, where X depends on `runlevel` and `##` conforms to regex `[0-9][0-9]`.
- a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu), where I gather that `K##_scriptname.sh` ought to be placed in `/etc/init.d/` and symbolic links pointing to the script placed in `/etc/rc0.d` (shutdown) and `/etc/rc6.d/` (reboot). Beside the fact that in that post, the most up-voted answer is incorrect and was not accepted, I am left with ensuring that the script (however long in executing) will actually execute to completion.

AFAIK a shutdown/reboot signal sent to the process management daemon, `init`, translates (among other thing) as "stop all current processes in an orderly fashion". `init` will do what it can "to honor jobs kill timeout values" [see `man 8 init`]. But what if jobs take longer in completing than the timeout values admitted by system policy (currently 5 seconds I think) ? I expect that to be the case for my script.

***TL&DR***:
A script `/etc/init.d/K00_ramdisk-sync.sh` with symlinks in `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/` executes at the beginning of every shutdown/reboot sequence.
***Question***:
How can I ensure that the script runs to completion no matter how long-winded, if need be by having the shutdown/reboot sequence pause and resume as needed ?

Comment: +1: @AndroidDev: It does address 75% of my question, but: --- 1) as pointed by terdon, Radu Rădeanu's post is wrong in multiple places even though it is the most up-voted answer. (Does a Lemmings quietly sleep in each and every one of our geeky souls, easily impressed by big karma-posters ?) --- 2) The link does not answer my doubt about whether the power-down sequence will pause while the scripts executes to completion. --- I wouldn't use that post as a reference for dupes.

Comment: @Cbhihe  Is there a different answer there which is satisfactory?

Comment: @Cbhihe  re. 'there' : The same link that you referred to in your previous comment : http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Belacqua: Sorry. Now I get it. Answer: No, there is none. The question wells up being "how can I ensure that scripts executing at run levels 6 or 0, when powering, down execute to completion ?" -- I found zilch in that department. That is the reason I believe my question is NOT dupe at all.